# QuickSight string to month name

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have some basic strings:

```
month
3
4
8
11
12
```

I want to output month names as well as them being sortable by month (not alphabetical):

```
March
April
August
November
December
```

Is there a simple way to do this without doing multiple `if`'s?
(Which doesn't allow you to sort by month)

```
ifelse({month}=1,"Jan",
ifelse({month}=2,"Feb",
ifelse({month}=3, "Mar",
ifelse({month}=4, "Apr",
ifelse({month}=5, "May",
ifelse({month}=6, "Jun",
ifelse({month}=7, "Jul",
ifelse({month}=8, "Aug",
ifelse({month}=9, "Sep",
ifelse({month}=10, "Oct",
ifelse({month}=11, "Nov",
ifelse({month}=12, "Dec",
"Error"))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data has a column which is date (object) as your source then you can add a new calculation column that formats the date as 3 letter abbreviation.

If your data is only strings add a new calculation column that uses the string to calculate an actual date.

Sort the table on the date column and just hide that column if you like....This should display just the months in the correct order.

I think parseDate() is the function you want to use to do this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parseDate-function.html

Answer (score 2):

We could make use of left() and formatDate() functions.

Ex: left(formatDate({datefield},'MMM-dd-yyyy'),3)

Suppose if we are dealing with strings, we could make use of parseDate() to convert it into Date datatype and then make use of left() and formatDate() functions.

Here is the documentation for the above-mentioned functions:

formatDate() - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/formatDate-function.html

left() - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/left-function.html

parseDate() - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parseDate-function.html

Answer (score 0):

To sort your original example by month, you could just add a number before

e.g

```
ifelse(Month=1,"01-Jan",
```